How to ignore light source on main camera in urp?
I want to make night vision camera like in outlast. And I need spot light only for this camera to light environment only through camera. In project that use built-in render pipeline  I simply used this script
public class IgnoreNightVisionLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Light limelight;

    private void OnPreCull()
    {
        limelight.enabled = false;
    }
    private void OnPreRender()
    {
        limelight.enabled = false;
    }
    private void OnPostRender()
    {
        limelight.enabled = true;
    }
}

and MainCamera was ignoring light source from night vision camera successfully. But in URP project I think render is working other way so this script is not working anymore. I also tried just set special layer to light source and ignore it in culling mask of MainCamera but this also doesn't work. I also didn't find any solution in google so I don't know how can i fix this. If there are any other simple ways to create night vision camera that will light environment only for itself it'll be nice to get this

can you ignore it by layer?

It is not working. As i know, rendering light does not working as rendering 3d objects, so even if I trying to ignore this by layer it is not working. But if I do the same thing for 3d objects - camera will ignore that

hmm, that seems dumb. Mind you, urp and lighting is a forbidden subject in this house so, i have other issues with it..  Id have expedcted the layer to work

Do you mean just giving a separate layer to the light source and then removing that layer from the list in the camera component's culling mask? If yes, that doesn't work, neither in URP nor in Built-in; I've tried everything I could. I can send screenshots as proof.

oh I believe you, it just seems like that would be the right way. Im sure Ive seen something about this on a youtube video

Could you please send me this video if you find it?

TBH I wasnt planning on hunting through the bowels of youtube trying to find it, but I have seen something where they had like torches and those torches werent rendered on all cameras, but with that info, I would have as much chance of finding it as you do

okay, thank you!

Not tested but I guess from this thread you can go through RenderPipelineManager and do something like
public class CameraLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
    [SerializeField] private Light _light;
    
    void OnEnable()
    {
        RenderPipelineManager.beginCameraRendering += OnBeginCameraRendering;
        RenderPipelineManager.endCameraRendering += OnEndCameraRendering;
    }
    
    void OnDisable()
    {
        RenderPipelineManager.beginCameraRendering -= OnBeginCameraRendering;
        RenderPipelineManager.endCameraRendering -= OnEndCameraRendering;
    }
    
    void OnBeginCameraRendering(ScriptableRenderContext context, Camera cam)
    {
        if (cam == _camera)
        {
            _light.enabled = false;
        }
    }
    
    void OnEndCameraRendering(ScriptableRenderContext context, Camera cam)
    {
        if (cam == _camera)
        {
            _light.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}


Yes, it works! Thanks you so much
